# Stack Two Divs When Screen Is Narrowed

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with an empty partition in the middle:

```
<div>
    <div style='float:left; width:10%'>A<div>
    <div style='float:right; width: 80%'>B</div>
<div>
```

[image]
When I narrow the screen, I want the A on top of B.

[image]

One solution that I've seen is to float A and B `left`, but the problem is that I need to keep that empty buffer between A and B when they are side by side. Floating A and B to the left causes them to be right next to each other while horizontal.

I've also thought about creating an empty fixed width div between A and B and floating all to the left, However, I do NOT want an empty buffer to stack in between A and B vertically.

Is there a different solution I could use here?

Comment: Media queries are the typical solution here

Comment: Protip: Don't use floats for anything other than wrapping text around images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a flexbox layout with `flex-wrap` set to `wrap` and with a `gap` of whatever you need.

Here's a guide with examples: https://web.archive.org/web/20211121030934/https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The suggestion of media queries by @j08691 is also valid, media queries are able to toggle various styles based on viewport width.

The suggestion of CSS grid by @Authentic Science is also valid, it can wrap elements based on containing element size, which can be affected by the viewport.

Also, here's an example using just `display:inline-block` and `margin`, the problem with this solution is that under most conditions element "a" will not expand to fit the whole row when they bump to separate lines, so they remain 10 and 80 pixels or percent wide each. Shrink the surrounding box to see them wrap.

```css
.d {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
}
.a {
 background: red;
 width: 10px;
}
.b {
 background: blue;
 width: 80px;
}
.r {
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 resize: both;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="r">
  <div class="d a"></div>
  <div class="d b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid is a good solution for this one.  See snippet below.  You will have to "Full Page" the snippet to see the desktop vs. mobile version.  The breakpoint is set to 720px.

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .container {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-gap: 24px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 80%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.box-1 {
  background: #7FB9D5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.box-2 {
  background: #FF5C5C;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">A</div>
    <div class="box-2">B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```